# Markdown in Facebook Event posts through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

How one can post to the Event wall using Graph API with Markdown formatting? It is not clear from API docs.

I am tried to use `POST /v2.6/EVENT_ID/feed` query with Markdown in `message` field but end up with raw text in the result.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @MajorMajor unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify markdown formatting

```
message=# Hello world&formatting=MARKDOWN
```